# numerical computation locks up ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to implement an id obfuscation scheme, with a simple hash borrowed elsewhere. i've added a method on the application helper:

```
  @@M_ID = 2**31-1
  @@PRIME = 1580030173
  @@PRIME_INVERSE = 59260789 # (calculated from MAXID and PRIME offline)

  def obfuscate_id(x)
    if x
      return ((x * @@PRIME) & @@M_ID)
    else
      x
    end
  end
```

for some reason, whenever this is called, ruby locks up, and starts eating up disk space on my mac... like - gigs of it. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure `x` is a number?  I could see this happening if `x` was a string - in Ruby, string times number gives you repeated string concatenation:

```
irb(main):004:0> "hi" * 32
=> "hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi"
```

And your `@@PRIME` is certainly big enough to eat obscene amounts of memory.  If that's the case, adding `to_i` should fix it (and your conditional could go away):

```
irb(main):007:0> "hi".to_i * 32
=> 0
irb(main):008:0> "32".to_i * 32
=> 1024
```

Hope that helps!